# Arduino String.replace() not working after file name change

Tags: string, replace, arduino, esp8266, arduino-esp8266

I have encountered a strange failure when this code runs on my NodeMCU 0.9 board. It is basically getting http code from an API in the following format:

```
<abbr title="klokken">kl</abbr> 11â€“12
```

In this case I want to isolate the 11 and 12 by first removing the first 42 characters which works perfectly fine and then replacing the â€“ with --. When I open a sketch and paste this program in it it runs perfectly fine and returns 11--12 **but when I save this program under a random name it is rebuilt and for some reason doesn't replace the characters properly** it then returns 11â€“12.
I have tried to replace different parts of the string when it was rebuilt which worked fine but for some reason I can't seem to either find the index of nor replace the three strange characters.

```
http.begin(URL_time);
  int httpCode = http.GET();
  String timerange;
  if(httpCode > 0){
    timerange = http.getString();
    timerange.remove(0,42);
    timerange.replace("â€“", "--");
    Serial.println(timerange);
```

Thus my question is if anyone knows how to work around this issue apart from not saving my code. Feel free to ask me to elaborate on my question when needed.

Answer (score 0):

The string you're receiving is encoded in Windows Latin 1 (ISO 8859-1), and you're (probably) using UTF-8. What you need is to re-encode the string properly.